# Stop Gulp Removing Unused Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, gulp, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

I am using Gulp via a Laravel project and I have javascript functions that I keep in one file that I then reference from the template when the page loads.

The issue is Gulp removes unused functions when it complies the javascript files.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to show Gulp script and configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have just found the answer, I'll post below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, found the answer.
Edit configuration in `/node_modules/laravel-elixir/dist/Config.js`

Lines 283 - 300:

```
    /*
 |----------------------------------------------------------------
 | UglifyJS Parser/Compressor/Beautifier
 |----------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | UglifyJS is a JavaScript parser/compressor/beautifier.
 | It'll minify your JavaScript with ease and has an option to
 | mangle your code.
 |
 */

  uglify: {
    options: {
      compress: {
        drop_console: Elixir.inProduction
      }
    }
  }
```

To stop the removal of unused functions add `unused: false` to the compress options.

Change to:

```
    /*
 |----------------------------------------------------------------
 | UglifyJS Parser/Compressor/Beautifier
 |----------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | UglifyJS is a JavaScript parser/compressor/beautifier.
 | It'll minify your JavaScript with ease and has an option to
 | mangle your code.
 |
 */

uglify: {
  options: {
    compress: {
      drop_console: Elixir.inProduction,
      unused: false
    }
  }
}
```

For more information on available options go to the [UglifyJS Documentation](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress).